# How to Install Redis on shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, predis

I am developing a Laravel project and I'm using Predis for caching database queries. Now I have to install Redis on my server. Is it possible to install Redis on shared hosting?

Answer (score 4):

Shared Hosting (by the typical definition) does not allow individual users to do anything but upload files. If you need to use things like Redis, which isn't offered on Shared Hosting that I've ever seen, you'll need a Virtual Private Server. You can get one from [Vultr](https://www.vultr.com/) or [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) for almost as cheap as Shared Hosting.

Comment: Sorry for small oftopic. But i find shared-hosting with redis, memcached and tarantool, and, honestly i think they simply lie customers. What do you think? I think it's too different and expensive for shared? p.s. and all that service on with simple click button. Can't believe that :) Or maybe I don't know something?

Comment: It's possible that shared hosting has stuff like Redis, I've just never seen it and it would likely be insecure and show (everyone in the shared host using the same Redis system, and shared hosting isn't known for top notch performance and quality). Where are you seeing this offer?

Comment: I think i shouldn't put direct link here, it can looks like ad. But I can put some screenshots from admin panel for this service. I think redis and tarantool it's to difficult service for this.  https://bg24.beget.com/docs/pub/b1f62cc769fcd0e88a73424ce41e111f/showFile/?&token=3gya2qz9877j https://bg24.beget.com/docs/pub/56f7771d30c084e042ac732c76a940fc/showFile/?&token=j1iivecltpfy . This cheap shared hosting and i don't believe that. But maybe i wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly installing, but if your hosting provide CPanel, they may have Redis already installed. Usually they mean it to be used with Wordpress plugin like W3TotalCache.

[Redis on CPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZjre.png)

Yes, some cheap hosting has git, composer, SSH, NodeJS and all the modern stuff that can be enabled on CPanel. In my experience, they crippled the SSH use by disconnecting after *3 minutes* idle and reject connection with ServerAliveInterval setting. So your terminal experience will not be enjoyable.

Installation probably not possible for most application, there's no apt or yum, or even sudo. It is not a full VPS, possibly you cannot update your software version by yourself.

There maybe other hidden limitation, but you need to find it yourself, YMMV.